# Using LDAP as a frontend for central login based on existing MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ldap, single-sign-on, ldapconnection

In my company, there is an "all purpose" application which is central and that we want to use as our central diary for users accounts and authentication.

Every users and ACLs are declared in this DB (which is a MySQL DB) but we are now using more and more external application and would like to connect them to this DB for authentication purpose (mainly).

LDAP is quite common for this and is well integrated in many external applications so I was wondering if it would be possible to build an LDAP frontend on top of that DB so that accounts creation and ACLs can be done as it is currently and external applications can connect with a standard interface.

Is it possible ?
Can somebody point me to tutorials or informations about that kind of operation ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OpenLDAP and OpenDS can be configured to use an SQL database as backend. A mapping can (at least in OpenLDAP) be defined between LDAP data and SQL data.

So, the remaining question seems to be: Can the mapping be defined so flexibly that it suits your existing database structure?

**EDIT:**
MyVD creates a Virtual Directory that you can feed with a database - and seems to be more light-weight.